# My God, it's full of stars

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, chat-stars

The 20-star-per-chatroom-per-day limit appears to have disappeared.

Tested with 2 different chatrooms over on CodeReview. Got up to about 70 stars before coming here to write this report.

Comment: You get +1 tasteful for that title.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whoops, yeah. The limit was temporarily lifted the day after the US election and we intended to put it back... and then evidently forgot.

I'm "putting that thing back where it came from" as we speak. Thanks for the report!

Comment: How many stars were born this way? ;-)

Comment: "The limit was temporarily lifted the day after the US election" Why?

Comment: @dorukayhan It was an emotionally charged day all around. I didn't make the change, but the commit message said "max love today", so I presume it was just a nice gesture.

Comment: Can anything else from that day be rolled back as well? ;)